# Hide page number on page, but count it

Tags: page-numbering

I understand that `\pagenumbering{gobble}` is usually the way to go to suppress page numbering on a page.

I would, however, like to have a way to count pages, and only suppressing to display their number:

I'll have a Title, Abstract, Acknowledgments and some other things that will take up a certain number of pages (subject to change) and then a Table of Contents. I would like to only start displaying page numbers at the ToC, but the page number displayed there should take into account the number of pages that came before it.

Is this feasible?

Best regards

Comment: Do you also have a header, or only page numbers?

Comment: I don't think that there's going to be a header. Just the page number in the footer, and it has to go. ^^

Comment: So it's the  `plain` page style. Try beginning with `\pagestyle{empty}`, then, just before  the table of contents, add `\pagestyle{plain}`.

Comment: This is working! 

Comment: a related alternative is to put somewhere on a page on which you would like to have no headers or footers (in the file, actually) the command `\thispagestyle{empty}`.  then you don't have to reset it.